# Cannot Insert Into PHP to MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert-into

I can read from database, but when I insert data to database, It said "Successfully Registered!", then I check my database , it didn't insert any data.

Register.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
<head>
<title>Register page</title>
<br>
<font size="5" color="black"><b>&nbsp;Register Page<br><br></b></font>
</head>

<body background=" images/background.jpg">
<form action="index.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Home">
</form>
<br>
<form action="Register.php" method="POST">
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Enter your information</legend>
  <table>
      <tr>
          <td>Username:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="username" required="required"/><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="password" required="required"/><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Email:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="email" required="required"/><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>First Name:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="firstname" required="required"/><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Last Name:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="lastname" required="required"/><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Date of Birth:</td>
          <td><input type="date" name="dateofbirth" required="required" ><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><input type="submit" value="Register"/></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
 </fieldset>
</form>


</body>
</html>
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $username   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $firstname  = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname   = $_POST['lastname'];
        $email      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $dateofbirth= $_POST['dateofbirth'];
        echo "user is :".$username;
        $bool = true;
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("userdata") or die(mysql_error("Cannot Connect to Database"));
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                {
                    $table_users = $row['username'];
                    if($username == $table_users)
                        {
                            $bool = false;
                            Print '<script>alert("username is used!");</script>';
                            Print '<script>window.location.assign("Register.php");</script>';

                        }
                }
        if($bool)
         {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users ('username','password','email','firstname','lastname','dateofbirth') VALUES ('$username','$password','$email','$firstname','$lastname','$dateofbirth')");
        Print '<script>alert("Successfully Registered!");</script>';
        Print '<script>window.location.assign("Register.php");</script>';
         }


}
 ?>
```

**SOLVED:**
I used PDO instead of mysql_ and mysqli_ .

Comment: You've got a missing single-quote before `'username'` (and you don't actually need to encapsulate column names, and should use backticks anyway) in the insertion query. You're not checking if the insertion was successful. You're using deprecated **mysql_** functions instead of **mysqli_**

Comment: Why you are still using mysql_connect , It is already deprecated , please use PDO instead of this.

Comment: I don't know how to use PDO, I hope if you help me if it better

Comment: You should test to see what `mysql_query` is actually returning rather than just assuming it was successful. That isn't the cause of your failed insert, but would help with troubleshooting and give you an opportunity to trap the error and report on the problem rather than just silently discarding data.

Comment: PDO solve my problem thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct the SQL:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username','password','email','firstname','lastname','dateofbirth') VALUES ('$username','$password','$email','$firstname','$lastname','$dateofbirth')");
```

To

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,firstname,lastname,dateofbirth) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email','$firstname','$lastname','$dateofbirth')");
```

**Explanation:**

In MySQL, field names are not enclosed with single quotes. Rather
they can be enclosed with backticks (`) to avoid conflicts with
reserved keywords.

**Note:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated, you `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an opening ' before username in your mysql query. Not sure if it's the problem, but it will cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to the INSERT problem itself, but rather to the routine for checking if username exists in the database:

```
...
$bool = true;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $table_users = $row['username'];
    if($username == $table_users)
    {
        $bool = false;
        Print '<script>alert("username is used!");</script>';
   }
}
if($bool)
{
...
```

Rather than iterating in your code through all records from users table, you can use SQL to do the job for you:

```
...
$username_esc = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where username = '$username_esc'");
...
```

and then only check if the query returns any row or not.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: I checked I can read rows from database, but I can't insert, It said"successfully register", but when I check database , no changes

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and found that connection was not proper and second you are using quote in fields name that is incorrect syntax so query was not executing. And my opinion is use mysqli_connect instead of mysql_connect it is old and deprecated. I have updated your code, hope it will help you :

```
    <?php 
//your values from post I just assign test for all
$username   = 'test';//mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password   = 'test';//mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$firstname  = 'test';//mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname   = 'test';//mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
$email      = 'test';//mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$dateofbirth= 'test';//mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dateofbirth']);
$bool = true;

//database connection
$servername = "localhost";
$username1 = "root";
$password1 = "";
$db  = 'test_001';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username1, $password1, $db);

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $table_users = $row['username'];
    if($username == $table_users)
    {
        $bool = false;
        Print '<script>alert("username is used!");</script>';
        //Print '<script>window.location.assign("Register.php");</script>';

    }
}

if($bool)
{
    //mysql_query("INSERT INTO users ('username','password','email','firstname','lastname','dateofbirth') VALUES ('$username','$password','$email','$firstname','$lastname','$dateofbirth')");

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,firstname,lastname,dateofbirth) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email','$firstname','$lastname','$dateofbirth')";
    $x = $conn->query($query);
    if ($x)
        Print '<script>alert("Successfully Registered!");</script>';
    Print '<script>window.location.assign("Register.php");</script>';
}
```

Comment: thanks , but when I use this code it doesn't print "Successfully Registered" and same problem

Comment: first check mysql is connection status, is it connected or not by using **connection_status()** , if connection_status() is returning 1, means its connected properly, then echo your query and try to run it in sql or comment here (after echo copy and paste as comment )

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the quotes round the field names, so your quest should be

INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,firstname,lastname,dateofbirth)
VALUES ('$username','$password','$email','$firstname','$lastname','$dateofbirth')

I would also recommend using a DB wrapper to auto escape your variables.

http://www.chris-shaw.com/b/How-to-connect-to-a-database-using-a-class

Answer (score 0):

**PDO solve this problem**
MYSQL made many problems but when I used PDO it  solved the problem

Answer (score -1):

Update your bottom code

```
if($bool)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users ('username','password','email','firstname','lastname','dateofbirth') VALUES ('$username','$password','$email','$firstname','$lastname','$dateofbirth')");
        Print '<script>alert("Successfully Registered!");</script>';
        Print '<script>window.location.assign("Register.php");</script>';
    }
```

Comment: @WaleedWalaaAldeanAbuZaid edit your question and write what code you are running now

Comment: @WaleedWalaaAldeanAbuZaid it should work now. well try once again by quoting table name like `users`

Comment: I did that , still have problem..when I have row with username "admin", when I insert username admin, It say "username is used", that means the problem not in the query.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name,username,password,status,picture) VALUES ('$name','$uname','$pass',0,'$picture')";
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.